# Join query and what do I do with it to display data correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores all the volunteers, and each volunteer will be assigned to an appropriate venue to work the event. There is a table that stores all the venues.

It stores the volunteer's appropriate venue assignment into the column `venue_id`.

```
table: venues
columns: id, venue_name

table: volunteers_2009
columns: id, lname, fname, etc.., venue_id
```

Here is the function to display the list of volunteers, and the problem I am having is to display their venue assignment. I have never worked much with MySQL joins, because this is the first time I have joined two tables together to grab the appropriate info I need.

So I want it to go to the volunteers_2009 table, grab the venue_id, go to the venues table, match up `volunteers_2009.venue_id to venues.id`, to display `venues.venue_name`, so in the list it will display the volunteer's venue assignment.

[image]

```
<?php
// -----------------------------------------------------
//it displays appropriate columns based on what table you are viewing
function displayTable($table, $order, $sort) {
    $query = "select * from $table ORDER by $order $sort";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // volunteer's venue query
    $query_venues = "SELECT volunteers_2009.venue_id, venues.venue_name FROM volunteers_2009 JOIN venues ON volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id";
    $result_venues = mysql_query($query_venues);

    if($_POST) { ?>
        <table id="box-table-a">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <?php if($table == 'maillist') { ?>
                <th>Email</th>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($table == 'volunteers_2008' || $table == 'volunteers_2009') { ?>
                <th>Comments</th>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($table == 'volunteers_2009') { ?>
                <th>Interests</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
            <?php } ?>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $i = 0;
            while($i <=0)
            {
                print '<td>'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
                if($table == 'maillist') {
                    print '<td><a href="mailto:'.strtolower($row['email']).'">'.strtolower($row['email']).'</a></td>';
                }
                if($table == 'volunteers_2008' || $table == 'volunteers_2009') {
                    print '<td><small>'.substr($row['comments'], 0, 32).'</small></td>';
                }
                if($table == 'volunteers_2009') {
                    print '<td><small>1) '.$row['choice1'].'<br>2) '.$row['choice2'].'<br>3) '.$row['choice3'].'</small></td>'; ?>
                    <td> <?php
                            if($row_venues['venue_name'] != '') {
                                // print venue assigned
                                print $row_venues['venue_id'].' '.$row_venues['venue_name'].' ';
                            } else { print 'No Venue Assigned'; } ?>
                    </td> <?php
                } ?>
                <td><a href="?mode=upd&id=<?= $row[id] ?>&table=<?= $table ?>">Upd</a> / <a href="?mode=del&id=<?= $row[id] ?>&table=<?= $table ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Del</a></td> <?php
                $i++;
            }
        print '</tr>';
        }
        print '</table>';
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------
?>
```

Comment: Note that using images with a width over about 630px results in the formatting getting messed up for people on laptop-sized resolutions - I'd recommend editing the img link to put a width of 630px. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General SQL LEFT Outer join syntax.

SELECT volunteers.id, volunteers.lname, volunteers.fname, volunteers.venue_id, venues.venue_name
FROM Volunteers_2009 AS Volunteers LEFT OUTER JOIN Venues ON (Volunteers.venue_id = Venues.id)

Comment: thank you.

 $query = "SELECT volunteers_2009.id, volunteers_2009.lname, volunteers_2009.fname, volunteers_2009.venue_id, venues.venue_name FROM volunteers_2009 AS volunteers_2009 LEFT OUTER JOIN venues ON (volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id) ORDER by $order $sort";

Answer (score 0):

select field1, field2, field3 from venues, volunteers_2009 where volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add any comment, but the syntax
select field1, field2, field3 from venues, volunteers_2009 where volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id
will only gave you volunteers with a venue; not those without a venue.

Comment: I want to go through the table and display the venue_name, if there is none, then display "No Venue Assigned". The problem I am having is to display the appropriate venue_name for each volunteer.

Right now I can just display venue names, but they do not display next to the appropriate volunteer.